# Windows Live SDK Authorization

Tags: c#, windows-live-messenger

I'm working with Windows Live SDK from C# trying to invoke directly the rest service for getting my oAuth token, but instead I'm getting an 401 Error. Unauthorized.

I have my application registered as Desktop Application on https://manage.dev.live.com/ and published so I have my own Client ID and Secret Key.

From my desktop application I open an Internet Explorer Window for Live Login and get my Verification Code.

With that code, secret key and clientID I invoke AccessToken.aspx on this way:

```
try
{
    string requestUrl = "https://consent.live.com/AccessToken.aspx";

    // Request the access token.
    string postData = string.Format("wrap_client_id={0}&wrap_client_secret={1}&wrap_verification_code={2}",
                                      clientId,
                                      secretKey,
                                      verificationCode);

    postData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(postData);
    byte[] postDataEncoded = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.ContentLength = postDataEncoded.Length;

    Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(postDataEncoded, 0, postDataEncoded.Length);

    WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();

    string responseBody = null;

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        responseBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    // Process FORM POST.
    NameValueCollection responseCollection = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(responseBody);

    return responseCollection["wrap_access_token"];
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score -1):

[The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408246/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-401-unauthorized)